# Automatic update of Text Boxes using a class of variables

Tags: c#, variables, binding, textbox

I am trying do the following in `C#` and `WPF`:

I have two windows called `Window1` and `Window2`.

`Window1` is a control interface which receives data from different sources such as UDP, Database, or hand entry; the data is then "sent" to `Window2` for display in `Text Boxes`. Let's say about 50 Text Boxes in total in `Window2`. I have a class (`DataSet1`) created which contains 50 variables of differenty types (`Int16`, `Int32`, `Double`, `String`, etc, etc).

`Window2` has a local declaration of the the class `DataSet1` contained in `Window1`. I want to collect the data in `Window1` and then assign it to `Window2`. This would be done something like `Window2.dataSet1 = dataSet1` from within `Window1`. Upon receiving the new data, the TextBoxs in `Window2` need to update based on any that have changed (or maybe just update all of them).

Now I know I can do 50 assignments within Window1 such as `Window2.TextBox1 = dataSet1.Variable1.ToString()`, `Window2.TextBox2 = dataSet1.Variable2.ToString()`, etc, etc. I just want to do this with one assignment statement which essentially copies the class variables from one window to the other.

I think I have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I do not know how to update multiple `TextBoxes` on multiple field changes.

OK, Sounds like nobody can handle this one or I did not make myself clear so I am adding some code to try and illustrate. I did get some simple binding to work by studying and following some examples; but I am still at a loss to make this work.

```
// Main control program
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 window1 = new Window1();
    TestBinding testBinding = new TestBinding();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Just for testing make a button to click to simulate
       // complex data processing
       testBinding.Variable1 = 10;
       testBinding.Variable2 = 20;
       testBinding.Variable3 = 50;

       window1.RemoteTestBinding = testBinding;            
    }
}

// Class module
public class TestBinding
{
    public Int32 Variable1;
    public Int32 Variable2;
    public Int32 Variable3;
}

// One of several display pages
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String fun;
    private TestBinding remoteTestBinding;      

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestBinding remoteTestBinding = new TestBinding();

        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Show();

    }

    // Problem is here, how do I return a string for the bound label but pass in a class??????
    public TestBinding RemoteTestBinding
    {
        get { return remoteTestBinding; }
        set
        {
            remoteTestBinding = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("RemoteTestBinding");
        }
    }
}


<Label Content="{Binding RemoteTestBinding}" Height="26" Width="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out and it works. When passing in the class of variables I wrote specific procedures which triggered to update all the text boxes. The final code looked something like this.

```
public String RemoteTestBinding
{
    get { return "Value to return"; }
}
```

Each bound text box was updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1. Do they really need to be 50 textboxes ? could you create a ListView that is displayed as a GridView that has a Binding to the Dataset

   **http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/gridview-in-wpf/**
2. Other option would be to create the controls programatically on Window2, after the results or Window1 are ready and assign its value with a **foreach** or similar

Comment: Actually I need more than 50 Text Boxes, I am displaying data across 4-5 windows each with lots of Text Boxes and Labels for them. This is part of a data monitoring system where the parameters are being updated constantly real time. A GridView or Dataset are not what I am trying to do. I do not believe a foreach statement gains me anything, I know the names of the parameters being read / manipulated and need them assigned to the Label/Textbox combination in the other window(s).

Comment: if you have a foreach you can iterate your dataset and your controls and assign the correct vale to the correct control instead of doing it by hand

Comment: Thank you Mauricio for taking your time to look at this problem. I still think I would like to make Data Binding work. I am looking to Bind the TextBox to a field in a local instance of a class. I think this would also allow me to not only update the data in the TextBox but also highlight the Box if data falls out of expected values such as too high or too low. I only need a one-way data binding since the data is only displayed in the Text Boxes